# Корректное взаимодействие front-end и back-end

Tags: java, json, spring

В написании сайтов я новичек. Написал фронт на HTML, CSS, JS. В плане back-end хотелось бы использовать Spring framework, так как с Java знаком. Планирую с контроллера отправлять данные в JSON и разбирать их на фронте посредством JS. Вопросы следующие:

1. Правильную ли технологию я выбрал (Spring и JSON )?
2. Есть ли у меня альтернативные варианты помимо использования JSP?
3. Будет ли более правильным вариантом использовать Spring MVC и пересылать данные через Model? (Этот вариант не сильно нравится, т.к. код портится тегами jsp).
4. В случае использования варианта с JSON , правильно ли пользоваться AJAX?
5. Есть ли смысл в генерировании JSP-страниц при использовании JSON ? В таком случае фактически HTML остаётся неизменным.

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правильную ли технологию я выбрал (spring и json)?

Подойдет. Посмотрите на [пример REST-сервиса](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

> Есть ли у меня альтернативные варианты помимо использования jsp?

Заменить jsp можно различными шаблонизаторами, вроде [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) или [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/).

> Будет ли более правильным вариантом использовать spring mvc и
>   пересылать данные через model? (Этот вариант не сильно нравится, т.к.
>   код портится тегами jsp). В случае использования варианта с json,
>   правильно ли пользоваться ajax? Есть ли смысл в генерировании
>   jsp-страниц при использовании json? В таком случае фактически html
>   остаётся неизменным.

Генерировать json с помощью шаблонизаторов (вроде jsp) - не самая лучшая идея. Есть специальные библиотеки для маппинга java-классов в json и обратно. Spring сделает это автоматически для методов класса-контроллера.

Comment: REST насколько я понимаю stateless. Если на сайте планируются пользователи с разными правами доступа, работа с денежными средствами и тд, обязательно ли использовать для этого сессии? Этот момент меня смущает. Если же сессии не обязательны, тогда собственно только REST

Comment: @Никита вы вольны делать так, как будет удобно, REST-это просто идеология некого web-API, насколько он *ful - это уже зависит от задачи. Вам ничто не мешает делать обычный сайт (с генерацией большей части контента с помощью того же jsp), страницы которого будут делать некоторые ajax-запросы.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

1) Если сайт уже написан, то лучше использовать spring boot. Так будет намного проще интегрировать фронт, через Ajax запросы пересылать JSON объекты на бэк. Spring boot по умолчанию уже имеет конфигурацию для десериализации JSON в Java объекты.

2) JSP - один из вариантов серверного рендеринга страниц. В вашем случае (написан фронт), можно применить клиентские шаблонизаторы (`javascript/template`, у jQuery есть что-то для этих целей).

3) Если проектируешь бэкенд как REST API, то для общения с ним используешь HTTP.

4) Да.

5) Смысла нет, бэкенд отдаёт данные, которые необходимо отобразить, а фронт знает как отображать эти данные.

Рекомендую взглянуть на [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) для инициализации проекта.